# Simply List a search from 3 completely different tables in php - sql consult

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this search tool in my News Archive page where I want the user to select a range from "A" date to "B" Date.

Example:

> From: [7] [06] [2002]
>
> To: ....[7] [07] [2015]

And 3 checkbox buttons:

> [v] News Ticker
>
> [v] Featured Article
>
> [v] News

I need to make a consult in 3 different sql tables, and get the result of them when the checkbox is selected like if it was only one... Let me make it more clear:

If selected the **news ticker**, **featured article** and **news** checkboxes the sql search will get all the data from the 3 tables: `z_news_ticker`, `z_featured_article` and `z_news`

And I already have the html-php part ready, I just don't know how to make the sql consult to get the result of those 3 tables...

Observation: The tables are different, there's no column related to each other

Here they are:

z_news_ticker table:

[image: z_news_ticker]

z_featured_article:

[image: z_featured_article]

z_news:

[image: z_news]

Comment: I'd like to know also how to make the search between those two dates in the news archive search box tool using the timestamp instead of data

Comment: Just do 3 separate queries, and display the results.

Comment: Hello @Barmar thanks for the answer, but there's no way to do it in a single sql query? with all the results ordered by date?

Comment: You can combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: But each table has different columns, so you'll need to add extra blank columns to the subqueries to fill in the missing fields.

Comment: thanks ^^, so basically that's the only way?

Comment: That's the usual way to do it.